# Can I use useRef to pass a reference to an element to a child?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I call I viewer object that mounts something into the element with id `tgmlviewer`. This works fine when I only have one such component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Viewer } from "../../tgmlViewer/Viewer";
import { disableTgmlPointerEvents } from "../../../constants";
import { XmlType } from "./XmlView";

type Props = {
  serialized: string;
  xmlType: XmlType;
};

const tgmlViewerId = "tgmlviewer";

export default function TgmlImageViewer(props: Props) {
  const { serialized, xmlType } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    let viewer: Viewer;
    const viewerElement = document.getElementById(tgmlViewerId);
    if (viewerElement instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
      viewer = new Viewer(viewerElement);
      viewer.load(serialized);
    }
    return () => {
      if (viewer) {
        viewer.reset();
      }
    };
  });

  return (
    <div
      id={tgmlViewerId}
    />
  );
}
```

Now I want to create multiple components. Each components needs to pass a unique id to its viewer object. Is it possible to use `useRef` for this?

Here is my best attempt:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, Ref } from "react";
import { Viewer } from "../../tgmlViewer/Viewer";
import { disableTgmlPointerEvents } from "../../../constants";
import { XmlType } from "./XmlView";

type Props = {
  serialized: string;
  xmlType: XmlType;
};

export default function TgmlImageViewer(props: Props) {
  const { serialized, xmlType } = props;

  const tgmlViewerMountingTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!tgmlViewerMountingTarget) {
      return;
    }
    let viewer: Viewer;
    const viewerElement = tgmlViewerMountingTarget.current;
    if (viewerElement instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
      viewer = new Viewer(viewerElement);
      viewer.load(serialized);
    }
    return () => {
      if (viewer) {
        viewer.reset();
      }
    };
  });

  return (
    <div
      ref={tgmlViewerMountingTarget}
    />
  );
}
```

TypeScript error

> ts: const viewerElement: null // The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.

Comment: Isn't [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) something you're looking for?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by passing a type to the useRef function. Would ref forwarding be a better solution than useRef?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
const tgmlViewerMountingTarget = useRef(null);
```

to

```
const tgmlViewerMountingTarget = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```